# In Vitro Meat Initial Production

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-culture, organs, biomedical-engineering, differentiation

I've gotten interested in the science behind in vitro meat, and I was wondering what would be necessary to create it. Would you initially need a primary culture, or an immortalized cell line? And how would you go about creating such a culture that differentiates properly?

The closest analog to this, I think, would be tissue regeneration but I'm finding it hard to figure out the answers to these questions.

Thanks so much!